# how to fix android studio changing flutter code

Tags: flutter, android-studio

There is something weird is happening in my Android Studio it changes code views, for example, I wrote a normal code and it works fine but when I want to see my code it is full of things that are not my code
it does the same to flutter itself codes[image]

this is Flutter Container Code...it works but I can't see the code... and it is fine in VsCode
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing font settings as default in Android Studio.

From menu bar, **File > Invalidate Caches & Restart**, to clean cache and open files again.

Answer (score 0):

just copy project folder and paste to other folder directory.
suppose your project is kept. and copy project folder from below folder

> C:/myflutterproject

create new project directory and paste project into new folder.

> C:/newmyflutterdirectory

open project from new folder.

> C:/newmyflutterdirectory